# delete a collection and all the including data (collections and fields)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

Im trying to delete a document X in collection Users but in this collection, there is another collection tasks is the collection Users. How can I delete all the data in the document X (includes collection tasks)

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(X).delete();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single operation in the API to delete an entire collection. Instead a collection comes into existence once a first document is added to it, and a collection disappears once the final document is deleted from it.

This means that you'll need to delete each document in the collection individually, preferably using [batch delete operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). Once you've deleted the last document from the subcollection, the collection itself is also gone.